# Grails URL Mappings security concerns

Tags: grails, spring-security, url-mapping

I'm building a grails app, and the default URLMapping provided by grails is `/$controller/$action?/$id`

I'm concerned about the security aspects of this catch all mapping. On one hand, it's a pain to explicitly list our all of the mappings, but on the other hand it seems like there could be potential security issues, such as forgetting to secure certain mappings.

By explicitly specifying the mappings, we have much tighter control over the URLs. It also lets us making more user friendly URLs (e.g. maybe we could pluralize things like using having a `people/john/` url instead of `/erson/john`.

Are there other concerns with leaving the default mappings? Is there a possibility that we could unintentionally expose the fact that a certain admin page is valid (I'll have to look more into spring security as to how to redirect to a 404 for trying to access admin pages for a non admin user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered yourself. Default url mapping  "/$controller/$action?/$id" is easy to use but may be used as hole in the case of bad controllers security implementation.

But probably the best solution is to place security checks even at domains level, so even if for error a user can reach a not authorized controller an exception will block him to do anything with the domains.

Comment: Yey, let's put security checks everywhere. Just in case.